# My submit button from tkinter to sqlite3 causes str can't be called error

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

my python program isn't working properly and it's something with the submit button and it gives me an error saying:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

help please. Here is the part of the code that doesn't work:

```
def submit():
    g_name = ent0.get()
    g_surname = ent1.get()
    g_dob = ent2.get()
    g_tutorg = ent3.get() #Gets all the entry boxes
    g_email = ent4.get()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = '''INSERT into Students, (g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'''
    cursor.execute(sql (g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email))
    #Puts it all on to SQL
    db.commit()
    mlabe2=Label(mGui,text="Form submitted, press exit to exit").place(x=90,y=0)
```

I'm not sure what else you need so here's the rest of the SQL part that creates the table

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students(
        StudentID integer,
        Name text,
        Surname text,
        DOB blob,
        Tutor_Grop blob,
        Email blob,
        Primary Key(StudentID));
    """) #Will create if it doesn't exist
db.commit()
```

I've been trying so long and couldn't find a solution to this problem so if you can help that would be great thanks

Comment: Please show the whole error, because it includes important information such as the line number that is causing the error.

Comment: Sorry man ```cursor.execute(sql (g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email))``` this line

Comment: What @BryanOakley suggested is that you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44057032/edit) your question and paste there the actual **complete** traceback. It has more information than just the line where the error occurs. Please provide all the lines that show up with the error (that is the complete traceback).

Comment: Not knowing anything about database access, my guess is that you have forgotten a comma after `sql`. Try `cursor.execute(sql, (g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email))`.

Comment: @JohanL that adds more errors: ```sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error``` and @iled I still don't understand so here's the full error code

```Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Downloads\tk window (2).py", line 46, in submit
    cursor.execute(sql (g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: OK, then `db.cursor` call should have a different syntax. The one you presented, treats `sql` (the string) as a function call, with all your replacements as in parameters.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what that meant.

Comment: Your code thinks that `sql` is a function/method but it's not, it's a string. So the syntax for passing that SQL command into `execute` is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

problem maybe in your line:

```
cursor.execute(sql (g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email))
```

try change it like this:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email))
```

Edit:

I call SQLite inserts in my simple app with this code:

```
data = (None, spath, sfile, sfilename, sha256hash, )
cur.execute("INSERT INTO filesoid VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", data)
```

and it works ok.

Comment: that adds more errors: ```sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error``` like I posted in the comments on the other one same line

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the values for your variables correctly. The way you've called `cursor.execute(sql())` makes the interpreter think it's a function.

You need to format the `sql` string correctly:

`sql = '''INSERT into Students, ({}, {}, {}, {}, {}) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'''.format(g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email)`

then use:
`cursor.execute(sql)`

EDIT:
or you may need to pass a tuple with data:

`sql = '''INSERT into Students VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'''`

`'data = (g_name, g_surname, g_dob, g_tutorg, g_email)`
and then use
 `cursor.execute(sql, data)'`

It depends on what those values actually are, and without seeing the database, I can't tell.